# A concise, simpler way to debounce the onclick event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, onclicklistener, debouncing

### Setup

I have a *Mobile User Interface* with its own **UI Back Button** in the bottom-left corner of the viewport.

> **N.B.** In this case, the UI is an overlay which appears *above* the web-page being visited, so as much as I'm a fan of `History.pushState()`, in this
> case, I have no specific intention to maintain a navigable history of
> overlay views using `History.pushState()`.

If the user has progressed into the UI-overlay by two or more views, then, whenever the **UI Back Button** is clicked or tapped, the UI-overlay should display the previous view.

---

### Issue

I noticed my **UI Back Button** can be pretty sensitive and it's easy to inadvertently interact with it such that the `EventListener` thinks it has been tapped *twice or even three times*, when the user-intention is simply to tap it *once*.

---

### Proposed Solution

Evidently some kind of **debouncing** is needed, as we might more commonly use with an `onscroll` or an `onresize` event.

I have written debouncers before using named `setTimeout()` functions and using `clearTimeout()` to repeatedly cancel the named `setTimeout()`, so that only one `scroll` or `resize` event (the very last one) actually fires.

But a debouncer with repeated `clearTimeout()` functions feels over-elaborate in this context.

---

### Further Issues

Ideally, I am looking for a simple, quick, easy, non-verbose way to momentarily deactivate the `EventListener` after the first click has been detected.

- I could use `removeEventListener()` - but this requires, in every deployment, specific knowledge of the format of the original `addEventListener()`
- I could use `AbortSignal` - but this requires `signal` to be set in the `options` parameter of the original `addEventListener()` and I can't count on that

Is there a simple and generic approach to debouncing `onclick` events?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an unexpectedly simple way to **debounce** an `onclick` event, requiring only two lines of javascript.

The approach sets the CSS `pointer-events` property of the EventTarget to `none` before resetting it to `auto` moments later:

```
const myFunction = (e) => {
    
  e.target.style.setProperty('pointer-events', 'none');
  setTimeout(() => {e.target.style.setProperty('pointer-events', 'auto')}, 800);
    
  // REST OF FUNCTION HERE
}
```

---

**Working Example:**

```js
const myElement = document.querySelector('.my-element');

const myFunction = (e) => {
    
  e.target.classList.add('unclickable');
  setTimeout(() => {e.target.classList.remove('unclickable')}, 2000);
    
  console.log('myElement clicked');
}
    
myElement.addEventListener('click', myFunction, false);
```

```css
.my-element {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  line-height: 100px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: 900;
  color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
  background-color: rgb(255, 0, 0);
  transition: opacity 0.3s linear;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.my-element.unclickable {
  opacity: 0.5;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="my-element">Click me!</div>
```

Comment: You could also use `e.target.disabled` and set that property on `setTimeout()` which I think reads nicer

Comment: Thanks @JoshuaRDBrown - that's a good alternative suggestion for form elements. Note that the `.disabled` property may only be applied to the following (form) elements: `<button>`, `<fieldset>`, `<input>`, `<optgroup>`, `<option>`, `<select>`, `<textarea>`.

Comment: Yep true, my apologies I wrote that after looking at the live code snippet and forgot it wasn't a button onclick event

Comment: No, that's my fault, @JoshuaRDBrown - in the live example above I've used a clickable `<div>`, but in my own code (which gave rise to the question) I _am_ using a `<button>`, on which your suggestion of `e.target.disabled = true;` works fine.

Comment: Perfect glad I could help :)